# A chain complex corresponding to the associahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

A definition often found is that an $A_\infty$-algebra is an algebra over an $A_\infty$-operad. here, a

- non-symmetric operad $O$ is $A_\infty$ if all $O(n)$ are contractible
- symmetric operad $O$ is $A_\infty$ if all $O(n)$ are homotopy equivalent to $S_n$, regarded as a discrete space.

As a geometric instance (of the former), one usually finds the associahedron. What would be a corresponding (at best, universal) $A_\infty$ operad valued in chain complexes? In other words, what is the chain-complex model for the associahedron?

Motivation: As for $E_\infty$-operads, one usually finds the Barratt-Eccles operad, which is built from bar resolutions of the Symmetric group, as a universal chain complex-valued $E_\infty$-operad. By the way, what would be the corresponding geometric instance?

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found [in the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A-infinity+operad#the_standard_dg_operad) or in [Loday, Valette: Algebraic Operads, §9.2.6](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf#page=291).